# get yesterday's date by selected date on Calender in php

Tags: php

Selecting a date on the Calender which format is:

```
YYYY-MM-DD
```

for instance:

```
2011-11-01
```

Then I want to display the yesterday's date (i.e `2011-09-30`) after clicking "one day before" button.

Is there anyone who know how to do it in pure php?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( '2011-11-01 -1 day' ) )`

Comment: Also, possible duplicate of [PHP: How can I find out the date of the day before a date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/781949/php-how-can-i-find-out-the-date-of-the-day-before-a-date)

Answer (score 3):

Well it would require a page load (if you are not using any javascript ajax functionality)

To get yesterday's date you do:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 day'));
```